# dynamic options for selected item in previous option list

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am writing an html which should contain two select tags. to make it clear, the first select tag includes name of continents and user should choose one of them. the second select tag should dynamically shows the name of countries for the selected continent in the first select tags.
could anyone please help me to understand how I should implement it by JavaScript function? what event should be set on the first select tag? should the event be set on the options or on the select tag?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta cahrset="utf-8">
    <title>Java Script Question Exam</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
    var la=["chili","castarica","cuba","jamaieca"];
    var as=["Iran","Iraq","China","Japan"];
    var eu=["Italy","France","Sweden"];
    var af=["Egypt","Morocco"];
    var continents=new Array(la,as,eu,af);

function ContinentFun(input)
{
    var cont=document.getElementById("continent");
    var selected=cont.options.selectedIndex;
    var e=continents[selected];
    var d = document.getElementById(input);
    if(d.length==0)
    {
        for(var j=0; j<e.length;j++)
        {   
            d.add(new Option(e[j],"")); 
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if (d.length<e.length)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<d.length;i++)
            {   
                d.options[i].text=e[i];     
            }
            for(var j=d.length; j<e.length;j++)
            {   
                d.add(new Option(e[j],"")); 
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if(d.length>e.length)
            {
                for(var i=0; i<e.length;i++)
                {   
                    d.options[i].text=e[i];     
                }
                for(var j=e.length; j<d.length;j++)
                {   
                    d.remove(j);    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(var i=0; i<e.length;i++)
                {   
                    d.options[i].text=e[i];     
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
         </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">

        <table id="t1" border="2">
            <tr>
            <td>Select your Continent</td>
            <td>
              <select id="continent" size="1" onchange='ContinentFun("country")'>
                <option>Latin America</option>
                <option>Asia</option>
                <option>Eroupa</option>
                <option>Africa</option>
              </select>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Country</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="country" size="1" width="15">
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
               <input type="button" name="Send" value="Send" onclick='PrintInfo("continent","country","t1")' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br><br>
    <textarea id="t1">
    </textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

it now works as well as I wanted.....

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<select id='continentSelector'>
    <option>Africa</option>
    <option>Antarctica</option>
    <option>Asia</option>
    <option>Australia</option>
    <option>Europe</option>
    <option>North America</option>
    <option>South America</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var selector = document.getElementById('continentSelector');
selector.addEventListener("change",function() {
     alert(this.value); // that will alert 'Africa' / 'Europe' .. etc

     // you can do your logic for the second selector here
     // eg. getCountriesByContinent(this.value);
},false);
```

Comment: sorry about that I mistakenly copied a wrong row from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continent fixed it

Comment: not really, I just wanted to make it clear...number of option is not important for me now. thing that is important is how to populate the second option?!!! I added my code above....

Answer (score 0):

On the first `select` box you'll want to bind to the `onchange` event. Your event handler would then make an AJAX call back to the server (supplying the selected continent) which would return the list of countries (prob as JSON).

You can then use that list to populate the `options` of your second `select` box.